# Dell Laptop Windows 10 Blue Screen of Death CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED when restarting

Tags: crash, windows-10, bsod

Dell Laptop was upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1. Recently been having an issue with Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) crash at random times.

Only error information is:

> CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED
>   :(

with a very obnoxious :(.

Dell Warranty expired three months ago.

After checking forums and attempting to reinstall drivers decided the best thing to do is just restore the laptop to factory state. The problem is that during the built in restore to factory process the computer must restart. During restart a BSOD crash will occur every time. Even attempting a regular restart will result in a BSOD, "CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED" error. So the goal now is just to restore the PC to factory settings, but the impasse is the required restart for this or a driver update is the required restart will always result in a BSOD "CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED."

Is there a way to restore to factory settings without having to restart? If not, then what are some alternative paths to just getting a clean restore?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 offers many Recover Options such as the [Reset you PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options) options which includes the following sub-options:

> #### Keep my files
>
> Reinstalls Windows 10 and keeps your personal files.
>   Removes apps and drivers you installed.
>   Removes changes you made to settings.
>   Removes any apps your PC manufacturer installed. (If your PC came with Windows 10, apps from your PC manufacturer will be reinstalled.)
>
> #### Remove everything
>
> Reinstalls Windows 10 and removes all your personal files.
>   Removes apps and drivers you installed.
>   Removes changes you made to settings.
>   Removes any apps your PC manufacturer installed. (If your PC came with Windows 10, apps from your PC manufacturer will be reinstalled.)
>   If you're planning to donate, recycle, or sell your PC, use this option and choose to fully clean the drive. This might take an hour or two, but it makes it harder for other people to recover files you've removed.
>
> #### Restore factory settings
>
> Reinstalls the version of Windows that your PC came with (either Windows 8 or Windows 8.1) and removes your personal files.
>   Removes apps and drivers you installed.
>   Removes changes you made to settings.
>   Reinstalls any apps your PC manufacturer installed on your PC.
>   This option isn't available on all PCs.

I would suggest starting with the "Keep my files" option and then moving on to the "Remove Everything" option if the first doesn't work; one of these two should solve this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't know who down-voted this or why. 

Any of those options are fine with me but the problem is when the process reaches the "Computer must be restarted" point the BSOD occurs. I can't do much of anything requiring a restart.